# How to make the headline (H1 with lines on the sides) with CSS only

Tags: css, html-heading

I have made some [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxzLT/3/) of such a headline that I need.

CSS:

```
body {
    background:url("http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/tiny_grid.png");
}

.main-container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #d00;
}

.headline {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font: normal 33px/1.1 Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #3E3E3E;
    height: 1px;
    border-left: 300px solid #aaa;
    border-right: 300px solid #aaa;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.headline > span {
    display:block;
    margin-top:-17px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <h1 class="headline"><span>OUR LATEST WORKS</span></h1>
</div>
```

This is not the full solution, because I use the borders around the text that push out the text from the parent container.

Is there any other ways to do it? But without additional divs and JS.

PS: The background image may be different, so I already try to put the same bg under the text but it's not the solution.

PPS: The "div.main-container" must no contain the overflow:hidden

Comment: please elaborate on the issue you're having. what are you trying to do? what goes wrong? be more specific so to ease others (and yourself) in helping.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're trying to achieve here... Could you explain please?

Comment: There is a link to the Fiddle. It is difficult to explain so please look it

Comment: I've seen the fiddle, I'm just unsure as to what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: I need to do the same as in the example, but the text sould be at the center of the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/olgis/qkNfm/, similar to @GionaF solution just without fixed width, but still you will need a container to get red line underneath the text.

As I understand your criteria for solution is:

- any background
- NO JavaScript or jQuery
- css liquid layout (NO fixed width)
- minimal HTML
- cross browser solution

In this post http://www.impressivewebs.com/centered-heading-horizontal-line/, they are discussing *"Centered Heading Overlaying a Horizontal Line with CSS"* a lot of different solutions as well as a cross platform issue.

My guess would be you are aiming for something like this http://result.dabblet.com/gist/1560674 
a neat solution with just one H1 .

Comment: Very good realization but it also does not work in Firefox :(. So I still trying to make something with it

Comment: Ah... there was a text-overflow which is removes the right border in FF. I have remove it and it's works perfectly! Thank you, this is the best solution!

Comment: I am glad could help :) Could you be more precise which solution you used!? As well does it works in IE7&8!? (it could be good to know)

Comment: I ware used this solution http://jsfiddle.net/zxzLT/74/ , but it does not work in FF because it couldn't to move down displayed as "table-cell" element using top:NUMpx. So now I use the solution that you suggest. And I can't understand how it works!:) but it works even in IE7 with [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard without setting a background on h1's text, so it's a tricky workaround.

[**Check this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/gAw3r/)

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <h1 class="headline">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>OUR LATEST WORKS</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #d00;
}
.headline {
    font: normal 33px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; /* no line-height here */
    color: #3E3E3E;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}
.headline > span {
    display:table-cell;
}
.headline > span:nth-child(2) {
    width:50%;
    padding:0 0.2em;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:1.2em;
}
.headline > span:nth-child(1), .headline > span:nth-child(3) {
    border-top:1px solid #CCC;
    width:25%;
    position:relative;
    top:0.6em;
}
```

​

Comment: the borders should not have the fixed width of the borders

Comment: @NikitaGavrilov you had fixed width borders, so i thought it wasn't a problem ;) let me think

Comment: Thank you, but it also has fixed width, but now of both — borders and text:) And there should be the wrapper ".main-container"

Comment: @NikitaGavrilov id doesn't have fixed with, but percentages, which are flexible. Check my edit with the .main-container in action. Try to add/remove text.

Comment: heh! Now i see, it's realy works. I trying to do the same with :before and :after insteadof additional spans. I will lat you now if I will made it. thanks!

Comment: @NikitaGavrilov very well done :-) for ie8 you can use [ie9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnot work in FF, so I will use the **olgis** solution. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @NikitaGavrilov oh, i see. Didn't test with FF, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

......................

Hi now check to this ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxzLT/22/)***  http://jsfiddle.net/zxzLT/22/

add this css

```
.headline {
    display:block;
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding:30px;
    font: normal 33px/1.1 Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #3E3E3E;
text-align:center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:relative;
}
.headline:after{
content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:1px;
    z-index:-1;
    top:50%;
}

.headline > span {
    display:inline-block;
    background:url("http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/tiny_grid.png");
    padding:0 30px;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxzLT/22/)***

Comment: I alredy try to put the bg under the text but as you see with different widths of the window the pattern may does not match.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with only one element `h1` (no `span` inside, no `div` wrapper) and no js (pure css) with transparent background:

http://puigcerber.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/centered-heading-overlaying-a-horizontal-line-with-css/

See it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/vLwDf/970/

Answer (score 0):

You could use border-right and left if thats what you need. See the link http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_border-right-style.cfm for more details on how this works.

EDIT You could put the borders on the h1 element instead of in the container of that h1

Comment: I have alredy use them, please check the Fiddle

Comment: I checked the fiddle already but is not clear at all what you need

Comment: hmm... it may realy helps, I will try to do it now

Comment: I have add the borders to the inner span of the H1, but now there is no way to centalize them vertically, or move the text up

Comment: why dont you just apply the border to the h1, no span, like : h1{border-right:something;}?

Answer (score 0):

if what you are trying to achieve is to have the containing div keep the h1 within its bounds, you should either try this:

```
.main-container {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #DD0000;
    display: table-row; /* i added this line */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
```

or increase the width of .main-container to something like 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

```
.main-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #d00;
}

.headline {
    display: inline-block;    
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    font: normal 33px/1.1 Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #3E3E3E;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.headline span {
    margin: 0px -40px 0px 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    text-align:center;
}
```