# Make graphics on left and right side of text change width depending on the amount of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to have an H1 tag centered between two graphics on the left and right of the text. The H1 text will be various widths depending on what page you are on. The dot on the left should stay on the left edge of the site and the line should extend until it reaches the edge of the text. Same for the right side. Is there a way to accomplish this by using CSS or even some jquery/javascript?

[image]

In the attached graphic, if the text was just "WHO YOU ARE" I'd need the bars on the left and right to grow wider to bump up against the edges of the text.

The background is a texture (hard to see in the example image) so using a solid color behind the text is not an option. :(

Comment: Why not have the line extend behind the H1, and just have a background color or something similar on the H1?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687385/how-to-make-the-headline-h1-with-lines-on-the-sides-with-css-only/

Comment: There's actually a texture behind the text, its really hard to see in the screenshot. Sorry. If I was to put a solid color behind it then there would be an obvious "block" around the text.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/NpCP5/

Instead of using two graphics we use one here that extends behind the h1 and set a background colour of the h1 (for the gapped effect). This could be achieved dynamically also with a minimum space either side for the line also using only css.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done with simple html and css. It uses the image you posted for background for the 2 sides and the main h1 itself. The text in image can't be removed with css , a more appropriate image is needed.
Try the following in a page in your browser. jsfiddle.net seems to block access to the image coming from this site

Use your browser console to inspect each element css and ake adjustments as necessary. The main framework is there, you just need to adjust to your liking

HTML

```
<h1>
    <span class="h1_left">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="h1_text">H1 Title Text</span>
    <span class="h1_right">&nbsp;</span>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color:#FC3;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/meq5P.png);
    background-position:left 0;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width:360px;
    padding:0;
    height:40px;
}

.h1_left,
.h1_right {
    display: inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/meq5P.png);
    overflow:hidden;
}

.h1_text {
    background-color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:40px;
}

.h1_right {
    float:right;
    background-position: 100% 0;
}
.h1_left{ float:left}
```